# how do I exit from Recursive Loop Exit

Tags: vb.net, recursion

How do I exit from the recursive loop from the code below. I would like to notify the end-user to select a checkbox in a msgBox before I exit the loop. Thanks.

```
Private Sub PrintRecursive(ByVal n As TreeNode)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(n.Text)

    If (n.Checked = True) Then
        MessageBox.Show(n.Checked)
    Else
        If (n.Checked = False) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Check a bex")
        End If
        End If


        ' MessageBox.Show(n.Checked)
        Dim aNode As TreeNode
        For Each aNode In n.Nodes
            PrintRecursive(aNode)
        Next
End Sub

' Call the procedure using the top nodes of the treeview.
Private Sub CallRecursive(ByVal aTreeView As TreeView)
    Dim n As TreeNode
    For Each n In aTreeView.Nodes
        PrintRecursive(n)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: BTW: Just a gentle reminder that it is an expected courtesy to people who have taken the time to try and help you to accept one of the answers on your questions.

Comment: Thanks John, I am pretty new to the site. Thank you for taking your time to help me with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to change PrintRecursive into a function that returns a boolean, for which true means "Stop"

Then change your recursion call to check the return value.

```
For Each aNode In n.Nodes
    if not PrintRecursive(aNode) then 
        msgbox("Notify User")
        return false
    end if
Next
```

A word of warning though, the messagebox will be displayed at each level of nesting when exiting the recursion. To avoid this you could add a parameter for the nesting level to PrintRecursive so you could tell when you were at the top level.

```
Private Function PrintRecursive(ByVal n As TreeNode, optional byval NestLevel as Integer=0) as Boolean
...
    For Each aNode In n.Nodes
        if not PrintRecursive(aNode,NestLevel+1) then 
            if (NestLevel=0) then msgbox("Notify User")
            return false
        end if
    Next
....
```

Comment: Hi John,

I gave this code a try several times, but my compiler tells me at the <- If Not PrintRecursive(aNode, NestLevel + 1) Then -> part that the expression does not return a value. Is there something else I should look into? Also, do you think using this type of method is the best to loop through all nodes that are selected in a treenode? Thanks.

Comment: That was just an example of an approach, but in any case I made a few tweaks to the code. Also, did you change the method to a function?

Comment: Hi John, Thanks again for the coding support and the tips on being a better user on this site. I actually switched the sub-procedure over to a function, still running into a couple of problems but it doesn't seem that I am stuck in the recusive loop. My work is cut out for me this weekend. Thanks once again.

Comment: BTW. I took a look at your site. You have some really good stuff posted there.